# using subequations

Tags: equations, errors, amsmath

I have an equation consisting of two parts and would like to use subequation for that.
Here's the code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{min}_{a,b,c} 
\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{w} + C \sum_{i=1}^{l}\xi_{i} 

\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y_{i}\left(\mathbf{w}^{T}\phi(x_{i})+b\right)
\end{equation}

\end{subequations}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
final.tex:118:Missing $ inserted.
final.tex:118:Display math should end with $$.
```

Can anybody help with that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Paragraph breaks (which are produced by empty lines, too) don't quite work in math mode. Once you remove the empty line, the code compiles fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
  \operatorname{min}_{a,b,c} 
  \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{w}^{T}\mathbf{w} + C \sum_{i=1}^{l}\xi_{i} 
\end{equation}    
\begin{equation}
  y_{i}\left(\mathbf{w}^{T}\phi(x_{i})+b\right)
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for a swift answer. I have spent two hours on looking for this error and found it by myself minute I posted my question here.

Comment: BTW: use `\min` instead of `\operatorname{min}`, and it might be an idea to use the `bm` package and its `\bm` command for bold letters, then one gets `bold italic` not `bold upright`

Comment: another suggestion: instead of separate `equation`s within `subequations`, it's generally better to use one of the `amsmath` multi-line display structures; in this instance i'd suggest `gather`. separate `equation`s may not be spaced well vertically, and can break across pages.

Comment: There is a good example of how to do this in the `Short Math Guide to LaTeX'.