# How to left align a text in IEEEeqnarray environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, ieeeconf

I am using `IEEEeqnarray` environment and want to left align a text. How to do that?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\interdisplaylinepenalty=10000
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{C}
    p(t) = \sum_{k=1}^M a_k \cos(k\w_f t + \phi_k) = \sum_{k=1}^M h_k(t) \label{eq:pli} \\
\text{where} 
    h_k(t) = a_k \cos(k\w_f t + \phi_k)  \label{eq:plih}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful if you added a minimal preamble showing the class you're using and the necessary packages to typeset the example.

Answer (score 3):

without an example, this is untested, but if the IEEE class doesn't provide anything for this, the TeX primitive `\noalign` probably does something similar to what you need.

```
... \label{eq:pli}\\
\noalign{\noindent where}
 h_k(t) =
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. however this does not work in IEEEeqnarray environment. Thanks anyway

Comment: "does not work" doesn't give us much to go on. please supply a minimum example showing the class you are using (the different IEEE classes have different implementations of ieeeeqnarray)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong with what you are trying to do. For example, you haven't given `IEEEeqnarray` the column alignment specifier. Note that, as you appear to be using `\text` you must have the `amsmath` package loaded. I won't use that, but we'll come back to `amsmath` in a moment. A minimal working example for your equation may be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{lrCl}
    &p(t) &=& \sum_{k=1}^M a_k \cos(k\omega_f t + \phi_k) = \sum_{k=1}^M h_k(t) \label{eq:pli} \\
\mbox{where}\nonumber\\
    &h_k(t) &=& a_k \cos(k\omega_f t + \phi_k)  \label{eq:plih}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Note the addition of the column specifier `{lrCl}` when beginning the environment. The `l` will be used to left align the text and the rest is reasonably clear. Apparently the `C` is capitalised to give a little more space either side of that column. Note also the addition of `\nonumber` and `\\` for your text to suppress numbering and start a new row. I have also used `\mbox` so that I don't have to load the `amsmath` package. You also missed out the necessary `&` characters for alignment. This looks like:

[image]

Now, I don't think I've ever heard of the `IEEEtrantools` package before, and it's better to use a more supported and feature complete package like `amsmath`. The `amsmath` package happens to have a command just for what you want to do (`\intertext{...}`), and provides a number of useful display mathematics environments. The closest to what you want is the `align` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{align}
    p(t) &= \sum_{k=1}^M a_k \cos(k\omega_f t + \phi_k) = \sum_{k=1}^M h_k(t) \label{eq:pli} \\
\intertext{where}
    h_k(t) &= a_k \cos(k\omega_f t + \phi_k)  \label{eq:plih}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This aligns the text to the far left (which is perhaps what you really want). Note that it's far simpler to get this output, with no column alignment specifier needed, and only a couple of `&` characters. The vertical spacing between the text and the equations is also far better.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and helpful comment. I'll try to use  align envv, how to use equation subnumbers in this environment? like
a=b+c (1a)
f=d+g (1b)

Comment: `amsmath` provides an environment for sub-equations. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14027/using-subequations for an example on how to use it.